# How can I make the animation to be loop without starting from the first frame but from the last frame?

Tags: animation, keyframes

When the animation start the point light is at the bottom in the middle on frame 1 :

[image: First frame point light is in the bottom middle]

Then when it's getting to frame 120 the point light is on the left side but when it's starting over from frame 1 it's like jumping backward to frame 1 and start from there and I want it to continue nonstop and not to move backward but to continue from frame 120. Like endless animation loop.

[image: Point light is now on the left but will move backward to start from frame 1]

Comment: I'm quite confused from your Q. Do you want to avoid jump of object in animation loop or do you want to start from another loop from last frame 120 so second loop will ends on frame 240?

Answer (score 2):

### Loop - keyframe location

Location of object has to be the same on the first and last frame.
Blender doesn't play backwards, so you have to animate this backward motion.

For this simple anim ad first keyframe on start location, second on end location, third keyframe you can duplicate <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> from first one in timeline and just move forward in time.

[image]

[image]

### Loop - Follow Path Constraint

In *Properties Editor* go to *Constraints* and add *Follow Path* to your *Light* object. Than you can animate *Offset* parametr - set timeline on frame 1 ad keyframe Offset with zero (hit <kbd>I</kbd> when cursor hovering above Offset field). Go to end frame 120 and slide Offset value until light is at start location and hit <kbd>I</kbd> again.

[image]
[image]

**Note:**
**To be precise - offset end-keyframe (light location that match with start light location) should be on +1 frame of animation end-frame.**
It means that light will be on next frame on location of first-frame.

[image]

Comment: Found it: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/391/31447

Comment: @brockmann Thanks :) Since I'm for a "historical" reason stacked with Safari  I will have to test it, I saw some issues in comments :)

Comment: @vklidu I downloaded your test file and tried to understand how to do it in my project. for some reason when I'm moving the point light in time line it's not changing the position in the transform of the point light I don't see any of the position x,y,z values change like in your example.  and I also see that you two keys for each frame 1,60,120 what are this keys ? Why two ? I tried to add first key frame at frame 1 offset 0 then second key at frame 60 and offset 120 the third key on frame 120 offset 0 but when playing it's making some rounds and then go the other way.  not like in your examp

Comment: @vklidu I tried to follow this tutorial so I guess this where I did the mix between the two animation modes yours and the one in the tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jLqD2_cVdQM&t=9s

Comment: I think tut in link is quite straight forward, anyway I added key points into answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear, do you want the object to come back to the center or do you want it to continue further to the left after frame 120 ?

For the first case, see Vklidu's answer.

If you want the object to continue further and indefinitely to the left, go in the *Dopesheet* press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Linear Extrapolation* (or *Channel* menu > *Extrapolation mode > Linear Extrapolation*)

[image]

Comment: oh ok perfect  ;)